# Is it possible to redirect numerous but not all files from /root to a subfolder using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have moved about 450 files starting with 4 or 5 different words in a pattern, (ie car_for_sale_in, boat_for_sale_in) to a subfolder and asked google to take note but the bots aren't cooperating so until they do I have lots of 404's. Is it possible to redirect only files starting with car_for_sale_* etc from htdocs (root) to a subfolder? 
I have tried to study htaccess but it's not sinking in and I can't find the exact problem answered without issues on here to learn from. 
Help with the code will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(car_for_sale_.+)$ /sub-folder/$1 
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(boat_for_sale_.+)$ /sub-folder/$1
```

or more generatlly:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([A-Za-z]+_for_sale_.+)$ /sub-folder/$1
```

This directive needs to be in the htaccess file in your document root.

If you have mod_rewrite rules there, then you may need to stick with only mod_rewrite. And can use these rules (at the top of the htaccess file):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+_for_sale_.+)$ /sub-folder/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Many thanks for your time. I have an index.html redirect so I have used the last option and it seems to be working fine. I will try it on a computer which hasn't accessed the files just to make sure when I have the opportunity.